# "Error: Conditions 'partyd' do not match the set names from "snames" argument."

Tags: r, algorithm, minimization

Hi I'm searching to do the Quine McCluskey Algorithm of minimization of the following dataset

df3

```
                   Party Deficit EDP FRI NegRate
Belgium 2014-18       0       0   0   0       0
France 2013-15        1       1   1   1       1
France 2015-17        1       1   0   1       0
France 2018-19        0       0   0   1       0
Italy 2013-17         1       0   0   0       0
italy 2018-19         1       0   0   0       1
Spain 2012-17         0       1   1   0       1
Spain 2018-19         1       0   0   0       0
Portugal 2012-17      0       1   1   0       1
Portugal 2018-19      1       0   0   0       0
greece 2012-15        0       1   1   1       1
greece 2016-19        1       0   0   1       0
Ireland 2013-16       0       1   0   1       0
Ireland 2017-19       0       0   0   1       0
Cyprus 2013-16        0       1   1   1       0
Cyprus 2016-19        0       0   0   0       0
Finland 2012-14       0       0   0   1       0
Finland 2015-19       0       0   0   0       1
Slovenia 2013-14      0       1   1   1       1
Slovenia 2015-16      0       0   1   1       0
Slovenia 2016-19      0       0   0   1       0
Lithuania 2013-16     1       0   0   0       0
Lithuania 2017-19     0       0   0   0       0
Latvia 2014-16        0       0   0   0       0
Latvia 2017-19        0       0   0   0       0
Malta 2013-15         1       0   1   1       0
Malta 2017-19         1       0   0   0       0
```

I've managed to do the Truthtable,

```
Truth<- truthTable(df3, outcome = "NegRate", complete = TRUE, show.cases = TRUE, sort.by = c("incl", "n"))
Truth
```

however when I try to do minimization:

```
df3.qm <- minimize(Truth, method = "QMC", details = TRUE, show.cases = TRUE)
df3.qm
```

it appears: "Error: Conditions 'partyd' do not match the set names from "snames" argument."

Someone knows how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the dedicated QCA with R forum, here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qcawithr/mTBTEOO8L78

It all depends on the version of the QCA package you are using, and even more specifically on which version of the package admisc (these two packages rely heavily on each other). Should you upgrade to their latest respective versions, this error disappears.